# TeamCity and YouTrack in under 1GB

Tags: teamcity, youtrack

I am trying to setup YouTrack and TeamCity on a VM with less than 1GB running on Windows.  There will be a very low usage (both users and requests).  This is a POC environment, if it works I may push it onto an extra-small or small Azure or Amazon VM instance.

Anyone has got this to work?

PS: I understand that this is way below JetBrains recommended settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried installing WARs under TomCat and I could not get TeamCity to play nice in TomCat 7.  I ended up using the out of the box installers provided by JetBrains and all worked fine.

Comment: You mean you are using it on Windows? Both systems together? How did you handle url and port conflict?

Answer (score 1):

I have a running YouTrack instance with only 256MB RAM allocated (never tried a smaller value), on an old server with only 1GB RAM, under Debian. It feels pretty responsive, but I'm the only user so far :D

If you're using Windows XP, it might work ok, if Team City would run with only 256MB RAM.

Is there a specific need for using TeamCity, or you need it only for integrating YouTrack with Git/Mercurial/SVN?

Comment: Yeah, I need TeamCity for continuous integration.

Comment: In that case, you might give Windows XP or Windows Server 2003 a try and see the results. However, 1GB of RAM seems way too little. Also, be prepared to fine tune the running services of your Windows installation.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved same problem in the next way:

1. Installed application on VM with more than 1 GB memory.
2. Configured my application.
3. Reduced size(memory) of the VM to 700 Mb available

As application was used JetBrains YouTrack 6.0 with 250 issues and 3 users. It was failing to install from msi package on VM with 700 Mb of memory. After processing mentioned steps it works fine.